# Single Quote issue with gawk and shell script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I am writing a small script to map all the current memory being used by services running in a server. However, I am facing a problem doing that. My script is quite simple. I'm using pmap to find out memory being used and trying add up all the pid of a service running.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=`$pgrep java`
wc=`$pmap -x $result | wc -l`
gawk=`$pmap -x $result | gawk 'NR==$wc{print $3}'`

echo "$gawk"
```

Now, my problem is that gawk uses **single quote** when searching for a specific pattern **(gawk 'NR==$wc{print $3}')** but shell script gives me error because then meaning of **single quote** is different in shell from gawk.

Comment: The single quotes around the awk script are for the shell, not awk. awk never sees them. What problem are you having here exactly? What error are you getting? Does using `$(...)` instead of backticks help? (They have saner quoting rules, are the modern version of that feature and nest correctly if needed.)

Comment: Is `pmap` the name of a variable or the name of a command? If the latter, get rid of the `$` from in front of it. Also, always quote your shell variables (e.g. use `"$result"`, not `$result`) to avoid nasty side-effects.

Comment: so basically pmap is a command in linux which basically adds up virtual mem, resident mem and shared mem. I am trying to write a script to add up all the memory being used. so basically, what I am trying to in linux command line would be # pmap -x 1232 | gawk 'NR==314{print $3}' where 1232 is pid of a process running in the server. If I run that command in command line it works but when I put it in shell, the single quote doesn't work because in shell it has different meaning.

Comment: This statement is a problem  do not use commands as variable names. -- gawk=`$pmap -x $result | gawk 'NR==$wc{print $3}'`

Comment: Passing the shell variable `$wc` to awk can be done like this: `awk -v wc="$wc" 'NR==wc{print $3}'`. However, it looks like this is the least of your worries...please [edit] your question to show us an example of your input and explain what you're trying to do with it - at the moment, it is unclear.

Comment: Thanks jim mcnamara, you're right and it was a mistake and I wasn't really aware about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it looks like you're trying to do this:

```
pmap -x "$(pgrep java)" | awk '{s=$3}END{print s}'
```

This prints the third column of the last line of the output of `pmap -x`, with the PID of the running java process. In some versions of awk, you can simply do `'END{print $3}'` but this isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks Tom Fenech, I just learned something new and it totally works. That's the exact tweak I looking for, to be honest I need to work on awk more than I expected. You've provided me with 2 different ways to do a single task (awk -v wc="$wc" 'NR==wc{print $3}') and (pmap -x "$(pgrep java)" | awk '{s=$3}END{print s}') and both of them works.

Comment: @linuxaarif happy to help. Don't forget to mark your problem as solved by accepting an answer. You can do this by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

`pmap -x $result | gawk 'NR==$wc{print $3}'` is not doing what you think it is.  (I have replaced your `$pmap` with `pmap`, but my analysis is only of the gawk command so if that is incorrect it should be irrelevant.)  The shell is going to pass the literal string `NR==$wc{print $3}` to awk, but it appears that you want awk to see the value of the shell variable `$wc` rather than the literal string `$wc`.  When awk sees `$wc`, it treats `wc` an an uninitialized value, so `$wc` become equivalent to `$0`, and awk will print any line whose content matches the line number.  The standard way to pass the shell variable into awk is:

```
pmap -x $result | gawk 'NR==w{print $3}' w=$wc
```

This assignes the shell variable `wc` to the awk variable `w`, and will print the third column of that line.

Note that there are a number of issues with this shell script, but this seems to be the core confusion.

Comment: But calculating a line number to figure out which line is last is just pretzel logic.

Comment: @triplee Yes, pretzel logic is one of the 'number of issues'!  Tom Fenech's recommendation to use END is a good way to address that particular detail.

Comment: Thanks William Pursell, I am not aware about pretzel logic but I am glad that the tweak you provided me did work and I am very happy. I have now 3 different ways to do it and I really need to work on awk. Cheers